# SMS Code Not received - Envelope Embeded Signing

Tags: docusignapi

I'm creating an envelope using the following params

Endpoint `{{baseUrl}}/envelopes`

```
{
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "email": "{{signer1Email}}",
        "name": "{{signer1Name}}",
        "clientUserId": 22,
        "recipientId": 22,
        "smsAuthentication": {
            "senderprovidednumbers": ["{{signerPhoneNumber}}"]
        },
        "idCheckConfigurationName": "SMS Auth $",
        "requireIdLookup": true,
        "recipMayProvideNumber": true,
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "xPosition": "100",
              "yPosition": "100",
              "documentId": "1",
              "pageNumber": "1"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "emailSubject": "DocuSign API - Signature Request on Document Call",
  "documents": [
    {
      "documentId": "1",
      "name": "blank1.pdf",
      "documentBase64": "{{BASE64_DOCUMENT}}"
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent"
}
```

Then i'm creating a recepient view for this envelope to fetch the url using the following code.

```
{
   "assertionId": null,
  "authenticationInstant": null,
  "pingFrequency": null,
  "pingUrl": null,
    "securityDomain": null,
    "userId": null,
  "returnUrl": "http://localhost:3000/webhooks/souscription-bis?project_id=111",
  "authenticationMethod": "none",
  "email": "{{signer1Email}}",
  "userName": "{{signer1Name}}",
  "clientUserId": 22,
  "recipientId": 22,
  "xFrameOptions": "allow_from",
  "xFrameOptionsAllowFromUrl": "http://localhost:3000"
}
```

And i'm getting the url as expected. 
And when the user is redirected to this url and i'm requesting the sms code to be sent i'm not receiving anything.

So i just wanted to make sure that i'm not doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i contacted directly docusign support through the phone, it seems that it was an issue related with their SMS service provider. Now it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

so you have the actual phone number instead of

```
 {{signerPhoneNumber}}
```

in our API call? 
and that number is not receiving a text message?

Comment: Yes . Sorry for the late update. But after i contacted directly docusign support through the phone, it seems that it was an issue related with their SMS service provider. Now it's working fine. Thank you.

Comment: glad it's working. can you mark this question as answered please?